# How can I found out the database ip location on network only with query? (mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

How can I found out the database ip location on network only with query? (mysql)
I can debug with the query inside web application only.(add code of query that show db location inside executed function)

(I don't know with which db I working - on my computer or with db on other local network computer.)

ip on my computer for example : 10.0.0.07 and on other computer that also has same db 10.0.0.09

Thanks,
Yosef

Comment: if you don't know the ip where mysql is running then how will you get connected to it and get it's ip by query?

Comment: On serverfault: http://serverfault.com/questions/129635/how-do-i-find-out-what-my-ip-address-of-my-mysql-host-is

Comment: By query? I think you can't. Why don't you just check the parameters of the `mysql_connect()` instruction you're using anywhere in your code?

Comment: you right, In this way I find out the solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql> SELECT @@hostname;
+-----------------------+
| @@hostname            |
+-----------------------+
| localhost.localdomain | 
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'hostname';
+---------------+-----------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                 |
+---------------+-----------------------+
| hostname      | localhost.localdomain | 
+---------------+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: thanks,I execute both your querues but i get:  object(mysqli_result)[3]
   public 'current_field' => null
   public 'field_count' => null
   public 'lengths' => null
   public 'num_rows' => null
   public 'type' => null